# I would like to apply css to the first image

Tags: css

I tried `first-child` but I couldn't get it to work.

**CSS**

```
.post_locked2 img:first-child {
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="post_locked2">
  <h1>title...
  <h2>Subtitle....
  <p>.....
  <p>....
  <img class="aligncenter" src="http://www.what...
  <img title="RockDizFile" src="http://......
  <img title="Bullet" src="http://wwww.......
</div>
```

How would you apply css to the first image only?

Comment: What didn't work? What rules were you trying to apply? The `:first-child` selector should trigger in this case, unless there's more you're not showing us.

Comment: Are you using a CSS2.0 compliant browser? What browser are you using? As others have mentioned, that should work.

Comment: I just want to clarify that this question IS valid, and the previous comments are incorrect in their assumption that OPs code "should work". As a result, the question received a few undeserved down-votes.

Answer (score 11):

`:first-child` selects for only the first child of the parent element.  In OPs example `:first-child` would be the `h1` so `img:first-child` would not actually select anything.

Use `nth-of-type(1)` instead.
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype

```
<!-- in the head -->
<style>
.post_locked2 img:nth-of-type(1){
  border:5px solid red;
}
</style>

<!-- in the body -->
<div class="post_locked2">
<img class="aligncenter" src="http://www.what...
<img title="RockDizFile" src="http://......
<img title="Bullet" src="http://wwww.......
</div>
```

And here's another example of it in use: http://jsfiddle.net/FsEhD/

Comment: I'm not seeing anything at all change, even if I select something as generic as
div>p:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
What's browser support like? Firefox?

Comment: It's available on all modern browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). You probably ought to try to create a minimal test-case that reproduces this (jsfiddle perhaps), and post your own question. Leave a link here and I'll be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
post_locked2>.aligncenter:first-child {some:styles;}
```

or

```
post_locked2>img:first-child {some:styles;}
```

Comment: I have everything in the proper places

Comment: So maybe another stylesheet is messing around. Then you can try `{some:styles !important;}` or investigating the cause.